# Prints one time while using each method on instance that has 0 values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some basic comments on my post. It works well expect for one part, even if there are 0 comments, one empty comment is generated, well at least it's HTML part.

**View:** posts/show.html.erb:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <div class="comment">
     Comment:
     <%= comment.content %> 
     <%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete  %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

**Posts controller** method:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    @comment = @post.comments.build if logged_in?
  end
```

Check the screenshot. Notice that comments: 0 and yet one empty instance is printed.

[image]

Here is test for this specific problem:

```
  def setup
    @user = users(:kunok)
    @post = posts(:food)
  end

  def go_to_post(logged_in = false)
    log_in_as @user if logged_in
    get post_path @post
    assert_template 'posts/show'
  end

  test "if there is only 1 comment, there should be only 1 comment displayed" do
    go_to_post true
    assert @post.comments.count == 1 # pass
    assert_select 'div.comment', count: 1 # failure
  end
```

Which resulted with this failure:

> 1) Failure:
>   PostCommentsTest#test_if_there_is_only_1_comment,_there_should_be_only_1_comment_displayed [/home/kunok/dev/food-social-app/test/integration/post_comments_test.rb:29]:
>   Expected exactly 1 element matching "div.comment", found 2..
>   Expected: 1
>     Actual: 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@post.comments.build
```

actually changes @post.comments collection by adding a new comment there. You could instantiate a new comment directly instead in order to avoid that problem

```
@comment = Comment.new
```